# Access to the path '/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/ibtool-manifests' is denied

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I am developing an IOS mobile application. I am using Visual Studio 2019 for the development and use iPhoneSimulator to test the application, after connecting to the mac device. Suddenly I am getting an error as preceding.

[image]

```
MessagingRemoteException: An error occurred on client Build162090 while executing a reply for topic xvs/Build/16.2.0.90/execute-task/Sprint.SESAT.iOS/a303cd7002fIBTool
UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/ibtool-manifests' is denied.
IOException: Permission denied
```

Anyone ever faced this issue before, I am 100% sure that it is not related to any recent code changes, thus providing codes wouldn't help here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was actually sure about that this has nothing to do with my recent code changes, thus I did the preceding things first.

1. Clean the solution and rebuild
2. Delete the bin and obj folder manually and then rebuild

But I was getting the error again, the only thing which worked for me is **restating the visual studio and open the project again**. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have this problem since the last update of VS2019. Thanks for sharing. Did you report this to Microsoft?

Comment: @JonasRembratt Not yet.

Comment: It blows my mind how many build errors Xamarin iOS projects have that can be fixed by a close and reopen of VS.